# Steiner tree to minimise travelling distance: Building roads to connect a network of points

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we have four points in a unit square, as described in the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705844/connecting-square-vertexes-with-minimal-road). We are tasked with building a network of roads that connect all the cities. The *travelling distance (T)* of this network is defined as the sum of the distance you must travel along a road to get from point A to B, and point A to C, ... and all six combinations of points.

Suppose we're given a certain budget, which will enable us to construct a length *L* of roads. Where should we build the roads, to minimise *T*? And what is the relation between *L* and *T*?

As the question linked to above describes, there are no solutions possible if *L* < 1+√3. When L = 1+√3, it is only possible to construct one network to connect all the cities (the first option in the diagram below). Here, *T* = 2*(2/√3) + 4*(1+1/√3) = 4 + 8/√3 =  8.6188...

If we were given slightly more budget, the best use (I believe) would be to shift the two junction points slightly closer together. Once *L* = 2√2, the network simplifies to two roads, from A to C, and B to D, and now *T* = 6√2 (the second option in the diagram below).

Then, as *L* increases, the optimal network evolves - each infinitesimal unit of road seems to reduce T by approximately 0.76 units.  Once *L* = 4 + 2√2 , we can construct a network that connects each point to the other, and *T* = 4 + 2√2.
[image: The diagram]

But is this process which I show in the diagram the optimal process? And what would the general process be if there was a larger network of cities?

Comment: In the last diagram, the distance travelled should be $4+2\sqrt2$, no?

Comment: I guess this problem is at least as hard as the [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem), which is already NP-hard.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - sorry, you're right.